# Entity Framework, fetching data keeps loading without result when including one to many relationship item

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I have an employee entity with 1 to many relation with certificates ( 1 employee can have multiple certifications) below are my entity classes

```
    public sealed class UserProfileAggregate : AggregateRoot<UserProfileId>
    {
    private readonly List<Certificate> _certificates = [];

    [JsonIgnore]
    public JobTitleId JobTitleId { get; private set; }
    public JobTitle JobTitle { get; private set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public DepartmentId DepartmentId { get; private set; }
    public Department Department { get; private set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public SectionId SectionId { get; private set; }
    public Section Section { get; private set; }

    public DateTime JoinDate { get; private set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<Certificate> Certifications => _certificates.ToList();

    ...
    }

    public class Certificate : Entity<CertificateId>
    {
    public string Title { get; }

    public string IssuedBy { get; }

    public Country Country { get; }

    public DateTime CertificateDate { get; }

    public UserProfileAggregate UserProfileAggregate { get; }
    }
```

and relation is defined like so

```
    builder.HasMany(up => up.Certificates)
   .WithOne()
   .HasForeignKey("UserProfileAggregateId")
   .IsRequired();
```

when i use entityframework core to fetch the user profile, I am not getting any result, and the API keeps loading forever.

```
    public async Task<List<UserProfileAggregate>> GetUserProfiles()
    {
        var result = await _dbContext.UserProfiles
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(up => up.JobTitle)
            .Include(up => up.Department)
            .Include(up => up.Section)
            .Include(up => up.Certifications)
            .ToListAsync();

        return result;
    }
```

Everything works fine is i remove the "Include(up => up.Certifications)"

I tried fetching certification data alone then binding it with the userprofile object, it works but that is not what i want. I want to be able to get the full object with all information.

below is the query generated

```
SELECT [u].[Id], [u].[DepartmentId], [u].[JobTitleId], [u].[JoinDate], [u].[SectionId], [j].[Id], [j].[Level], [j].[Title], [d].[Id], [d].[Name], [s].[Id], [s].[Name], [a].[Id], [a].[Title], [a].[IssuedBy], [a].[UserProfileAggregateId]
FROM [UserProfileAggregates] AS [u]
INNER JOIN [JobTitles] AS [j] ON [u].[JobTitleId] = [j].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Departments] AS [d] ON [u].[DepartmentId] = [d].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Sections] AS [s] ON [u].[SectionId] = [s].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Certificates] AS [a] ON [u].[Id] = [a].[UserProfileAggregateId]
ORDER BY [u].[Id], [j].[Id], [d].[Id], [s].[Id]
```

Comment: The way you are defining _certificates looks wrong.

Comment: The issue may be coming from your default value for `Certifications`. In Linq there is the concept of [deferred versus immediate execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#deferred-query-execution). Using `_certificates.ToList()` is triggering an immediate execution which may explain what you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use ToList() within your entity class itself. Also please check for circular references and lazy loading where in the related entities are loaded as soon as they are accessed.

Comment: I tried doing lazy loading with no luck. and i made sure there were no circular references.

Comment: Suggestions belong in comments, they're not answers.

Answer (score 0):

I re-read the code, and stripped everything. I properly enabled lazyloading using LazyLoadingProxies and declared relationship properties as virtual. That fixed the problem.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer("");
});


public class UserProfileAggregate : AggregateRoot<UserProfileId>
{
    private readonly List<Award> _awards = [];

    ....

    public virtual IReadOnlyList<Award> Awards => _awards.ToList();

}

public async Task<List<UserProfileAggregate>> GetUserProfiles()
{
    var result = await _dbContext.UserProfiles
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToListAsync();
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: IMO lazy loading is not a fix. Now you have a "N + 1" problem. You probably had a [cartesian explosion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries#cartesian-explosion).

Comment: I agree, i am facing all sorts of problems after implementing lazy loading because i am loading detached entities that need updating. I will look into Cartesian Explosion.